# Get indexOfObject method without using Foundation objects

Tags: arrays, swift

by selecting **1st tableView row/section** I want to check if selected item already in **2nd tableView** ?, if yes then find that selected item **indexOfObject** in 2nd tableView.

```
NSInteger sectionIndex = [[allSelectedProducts valueForKey:@"productID"] indexOfObject:[allProductData[indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"productID"]];
```

this will return the index of selected object in allSelectedProducts, Returns the lowest index whose corresponding array value is equal to a given object.

I want to perform this same task in swift, how can I achive that !

In Swift I've taken `allSelectedProducts` for 1st tableView and `allProductData` for 2nd tableView both arrays with `Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>` type

I want to perform this task **without using Foundation classes**, can we perform that same task in `array` using `indexOf` in Swift !?

```
let productIndex = allSelectedProducts.indexOf(<#T##predicate: ([String : Any]) throws -> Bool##([String : Any]) throws -> Bool#>)
```

If we can, then how ?
please guide me how to use `indexOf`in swift

thanx in advance for any help

Comment: I've improved your question but it is still not very clear. Don't hesitate to use the [edit] button to improve it further. Also, please avoid using textspeak, Stack Overflow is not a chat app, take your time to type the words correctly. Thank you.

Comment: If you're already using `Array`s, then why don't you want to use foundation object types?

Comment: Unclear what the problem is. Since you know about `indexOf`, why don't you use it?

Comment: @NRitH I want to use swift array in pure swifty way...

Comment: @matt I don't know how to use indexOf in swift...

Comment: `Array` *is* a purely Swifty way.

Comment: Keeping objects as dictionaries (seeing your `Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>`) is a javascript solution not a Swift or Objective-C solution. Your root problem is there.

Comment: `Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>` is perfectly valid Swift, although `[[String : Any]]` is more idiomatic, as of Swift 1.1.

Comment: @NRitH Valid but keeping an object as its dictionary representation, instead of parsing it to a custom object, e.g. class `Product`, is a road to hell.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
let searchedProductID = allProductData[indexPath.section]["productID"]
let index = allSelectedProducts.indexOf { $0["productID"] == searchedProductID }
```

which is a direct translation of your original code

Comment: `let index = allSelectedProducts.indexOf(searchedProductID)`

Comment: @NRitH I don't think so, because `allSelectedProducts` holds dictionaries. The better solution would be to parse dictionaries into objects and define `==` to use `productId`.

Comment: Oh, man; you're right. So then `let selectedProduct = allSelectedProducts[indexPath.section]; let index = allProductData.indexOf(product)`.

Comment: @Sulthan its giving me `Binary operator '==' cannot to applied to two 'Any?' operands`